# Rulebook on how to eliminate variables in parameter (Cartesian equation of curve)

Tags: calculus, parametric

I was tutoring a student in Calculus II, who was working on the subject of "Curves Defined by Parametric Equations."  The excellent example of a problem that the student was facing was to eliminate the 't' variable from the equation where y = sinh t, x = cosh t.  Now, I am not interested in the solution of this specific problem, but the methods that was used in the solution (see the first provided solution: https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781285741550-stewart-calculus-early-transcendentals-8th-edition/645/exercises/17a/).

The student said the methods such as adding, subtracting x and y's wasn't in the 'rulebook' of substitution for variable elimination.

So, my question for you math professionals is where may I find this particular 'how-to-do' guidebook or procedures of how to find these type of solutions...say a cheat sheet on what to do first, second and then so forth in the methodical way of finding these type of solutions?

Comment: The linked solution seems like a rather roundabout way to use the standard identity $\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  That would have led a straightforward substitution method.  I've shared that with the tutee.  I'll still love to see the procedural guide.   This "how do I eliminate the parameter variable?" questions apparently come up often here too.

Comment: I don’t think I’ve ever seen a “bag of tricks” for eliminating variables, but I agree that it would be a great resource to have. Might be worth turning this question over to community Wiki.

Comment: @amd I tried flagging it for a moderator to move it over to the wiki.  It looks like it didn't happen.